# How to efficiently create a priority queue using every key's first value in a dictionary

Tags: python, priority-queue

I am fairly new to python and I am trying out how to create a priority queue based on a dictionary where it sorts the inputs as lowest first based on each key's first value. Like so:

```py
my_dictionary = {'a': (3, 'data1'), 'b': (1, 'data2'), 'c': (2, 'data3')}
```

I would expect to get an output with the order of **key_2, key_3, key_1** in some fashion. I only want it to prioritize off of the first value, the other values are simply placeholders. I have never used a priority queue in Python before so all help is welcome!

**edit** I accidentally used "{}" inside the dictionary whenever it should have been "()".

Comment: You've got a number of problems here.  Do you mean for `key_1`, `value2`, etc to be strings, or do you define those as variables elsewhere? With just this one line of code, those are undefined identifiers.  Even if you define those, this isn't valid Python 3 code because of the leading 0's on your numbers.  Your values in your maps are sets, so there is no concept of "the first value" in those pairs of values.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to be as general as possible to still leave some for me to infer of how to adapt. I will adjust the leading 0's. I was trying to leave the data types in a more general sense of data that I do not really care about as I am only trying to output a priority queue based on the values of 1, 2, 3, 4. I will adjust my question based on your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Did my answer give you the basics?  It is sorting the contents of your dictionary by the first element of the value, so it seems like it should give you a good starting point even if it isn't exactly what you wanted.  It couldn't stay a dict. because dicts don't have order...so it became a list.

Comment: I believe so, I am going to play around with it and see what I can get it to do. Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a priority qeue ? maybe not. just sorting the dictionnay could be useful.

```
my_dictionary = {'key_1': (3, 'value2'), 'key_2': (1, 'value4'), 'key_3': (2, 'value5')}

sorted_dict = {k:v for k, v in sorted(my_dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0])}

print(sorted_dict)
```

output:

`{'key_2': (1, 'value4'), 'key_3': (2, 'value5'), 'key_1': (3, 'value2')}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this gives you what you want, although it's a bit hard to be sure because your code requires significant changes just to run:

```
value2 = 2
value4 = 4
value5 = 5
my_dictionary = {'key_1': [3, value2], 'key_2': [1, value4], 'key_3': [2, value5]}

sorted_dict = sorted(my_dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])

for i in sorted_dict:
    print(i[0])

print()

for i in sorted_dict:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Result:

```
key_2
key_3
key_1

key_2 [1, 4]
key_3 [2, 5]
key_1 [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want a priority queue, where the keys are the numbers in your values, and the values are the data you want to get back. It'll require a little reorganization of your data, but if you have a lot of values, or if you are both updating and searching within your data inside of a loop, it'll probably be worth it.
https://pypi.org/project/fibonacci-heap-mod/
Examples of using it can be found at https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/fibonacci-heap-mod/trunk/test-fibonacci-heap-mod

Full disclosure: I ported fibonacci heap mod to Python from Java.

You could also do this with the Python standard library's heapq module, if you add instances of a class that sorts on one attribute (your small numbers) and allows lookups of the others (the key and list).  This could be done with Python's rich comparison methods - having them pay attention to what you prioritized, and having them ignore what you don't want participating in the prioritization itself.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I believe that I may have arrived at a solution.